# OWL-API getting an ontology from the OWLOntologyManager

Tags: java, ontology, owl-api

Is there a "simple" way to get a certain ontology from the `OWLOntologyManager`? I loaded a ontology and the depencies with the manager and i can access a HasSet with `OWLOntologyManager.getOntologies()` where i can see all imported ontologies.

There is also a `OWLOntologyManager.getOntology(IRI)` function BUT this function only works if the ontology has no versionID, too bad the ontology i want to get has a `versionID` and this function will just return null.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, you can use the `OntologyManager.getVersions(IRI ontology)` function to do this. It will return a `java.util.Set<OWLOntology>` that contains all ontologies that have the specified ontology IRI.

You can find the Javadoc for this method [here](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLOntologyManager.html#getVersions%28org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI%29).